# Convert a complexe object using Lodash functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I'm new to lodash and I could like to format an object, is there a way to do it with lodash functions or another optimal way to do it.

The initial object look life this:

```
var obj = {
 valuesStr: 
  { ref_str: [ 'REF' ],
    des_str: [ 'DES' ],
    desc_str: [ 'DESC' ] },
 id: 1
}
```

The resulting object would look like this:

```
var result = { 
 value: 
  [ { code: 'ref', context: '', value: [ 'REF' ] },
  { code: 'des', context: '', value: [ 'DES' ] },
  { code: 'desc', context: '', value: [ 'DESC' ] } ],
 id: 1
}
```

I tried this solution, but doesn't give me the expected result:

```
var res = {
            value: _.map(obj.valuesStr, res => {
            return {
                code: res.toLowerCase(),
                context: '',
                value: res,
            };
            id: obj.id
        }
```

Comment: could you put the whole initial object

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: updated with solution I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for lodash, it's quite easy to do with plain js

```js
var obj = {
  valuesStr: {
    ref_str: ['REF'],
    des_str: ['DES'],
    desc_str: ['DESC']
  },
  id: 1
}

var res = {
  value: Object.keys(obj.valuesStr).map(v => ({
    code: obj.valuesStr[v][0].toLowerCase(),
    context: '',
    value: obj.valuesStr[v]
  })),
  id: obj.id
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I made my solution work based on your answer tkx. I was just missing to point out to element in location [0] **res[0].toLowerCase()**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` method to create new object.

```js
var obj = {
  valuesStr: {
    ref_str: ['REF'],
    des_str: ['DES'],
    desc_str: ['DESC']
  },
  id: 1
}
var result = Object.keys(obj.valuesStr).reduce(function(r, e) {
  r.value.push({ code: e.split('_')[0], context: '', value: obj.valuesStr[e] })
  return r
}, {value: [], id: obj.id})

console.log(result)
```